# How to tell which term "overpowers" the other term?

Tags: calculus

Is there a definitive way to figure out which out of two terms is greater? For example, to do the nth term test for $\frac{4^n(n!)^n}{(n^n)^2}$ how would I be able to tell for sure which term is greater other than just putting it into a calculator?

Comment: Ratio test may give something. Here I would probably first take a look at the logarithms. A reasonable approximation is $\ln(n!)=n \ln n-n$.

Comment: For large $n$, we use approximations for $n!$ such as Stirling's approximation to make asymptotic calculations easier. However, in a general situation, say with some function that does not have nice asymptotics, such a definitive way may not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a number of results already proven.  $n^a \gt n^b$ for $a \gt b$, regardless of multiplying constants.  $a^n \gt x^k$ for any $a \gt 1, k$.  Factorials are dealt with by Stirling's approximation $n! \approx \frac {n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2 \pi n}$